# Create table showing the sorted absolute correlation of various variables with another series

Tags: r, sorting, correlation, ranking

I want the output show the name of each X variable, its signed correlation to another series, and its absolute correlation, sorted by descending absolute correlation.

Using the following codes I was able to calculate the correlation between a series (object `res1`) and the X variables (located within the `data2` dataframe).

```
cor(data2, res1, method = c("pearson"))
```

The above code generated the output below that shows vertically in the console.

```
         [,1]
x1 0.45683210
x2 0.62858863
x3 0.08457911
x4 0.41022052
```

Next, using the following code I was able to rank those correlations by their absolute value using the sort() function.

```
abs(cor(data2, res1, method = c("pearson")))
abs1<-abs(cor(data2, res1, method = c("pearson")))
sort(abs1, decreasing = TRUE)
```

And, I got the following output.

```
[1] 0.62858863 0.45683210 0.41022052 0.08457911
```

I want to generate an output that looks like a table or a dataframe.

In the first column you would have the labels of the X variable.
In the second column you would have their absolute correlation.
In the third column you would have the actual correlation.

And, this vertical tabular list would be ranked in descending order.  I think I have all the info I need.  I just need the codes to generate the output as specified.

Comment: I am not sure why such questions get immediately down voted.  I have seen very similar questions also experience the same fate.  Yet, invariably those questions are specific and ask for very defined coding assistance.  I would think it is just the type of questions that would fit the purpose of this site.

Comment: It is hard to answer these sorts of questions without an example of the data you're starting with and an example of the output you want. Without these, you're putting the onus on the answerer to imagine all the possible ways your input data might look and guess at what output you want. I would prefer to know ahead of time exactly what you want, and not rely on my possibly faulty interpretation of your description. Then I could test if my answer actually does what you want before submitting it, and without waiting for you to test it.

Comment: (Was in answer, more appropriate for a comment.)   It is good etiquette on SO to include example data and example output. This saves answerers' time and reduces frustration on both parties' part around potential misunderstandings. I have answered questions where I wasted time doing what the answerer said but not what they meant. And sometimes I've misread what they asked, but would have caught my mistake if output were specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by @Jon Spring is perfect. Here is the same code in `base R`

```
res1 <- c(0, 5, 2, 7, 1)
data2 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5,           # uncorrelated
                    x2 = 14:10,             # uncorrelated and wrong direction
                    x3 = c(0, 5, 1, 6, 0),  # very similar
                    x4 = c(0, 0, 2, 7, 1))  # somewhat similar

correlation = cor(data2, res1, method = "pearson")
names = rownames(correlation)
abs_cor = abs(correlation)
data = data.frame(X_var = names,abs_cor = abs_cor,cor = correlation)
data[order(data$abs_cor,decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Comment: I tested your codes.  They worked just fine.  They also were more efficient and transparent than the other very good answer.  Because of that, I gave you the best answer including the +50 bounty.

Answer (score 6):

I think I understand your question, but I'm not 100% sure.

I start with some example data. I know by eye that x1 and x2 are not good fits, that x3 is a very good fit, and x4 is almost as good.

```
res1 <- c(0, 5, 2, 7, 1)
data2 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5,           # uncorrelated
                x2 = 14:10,             # uncorrelated and wrong direction
                x3 = c(0, 5, 1, 6, 0),  # very similar
                x4 = c(0, 0, 2, 7, 1))  # somewhat similar
```

My answer relies on `dplyr`, and is not the most concise, but should be clear to follow.

```
library(dplyr)
cor(data2, res1, method = "pearson") %>% 
  tibble::as.tibble(rownames = "X_var") %>% # Edit: using suggestion in comment, was
         # as.data.frame() %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(varrownames = "X_var") %>%  
  convert row names into a new column "X_var" 
  mutate(abs_cor = abs(V1)) %>%          # add absolute correlation
  arrange(-abs_cor) %>%                  # sort by descending abs correlation
  select(X_var, abs_cor, cor = V1)       # display in order and rename V1
```

Output

```
  X_var   abs_cor        cor
1    x3 0.9822125  0.9822125
2    x4 0.7058824  0.7058824
3    x1 0.2169305  0.2169305
4    x2 0.2169305 -0.2169305
```

Comment: `rownames_to_column` is from the `tibble` package

Comment: Thank you! Updated.

Comment: Thanks for a very interesting answer.  I will test it soon.

Comment: You can simplify this slightly by using `as_tibble(rownames = "X_var")`

Answer (score 0):

Sada93 answer, as shown above is great.  I have now used this set of codes numerous times and they work perfectly well.  However, I uncovered that his last line of code where he uses the order() function to sort the absolute correlation in descending order can simply be replaced by using the Viewer within R Studio and sorting in descending order by clicking above the abs(correlation) column.